# Cleaning text after beautiful soup removing specific patterns

Tags: regex, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

The ultimate goal is to have a clean plain text for voice processing. That means I need to remove sub-headers, links, bullet points etc. The code below shows steps I have taken to clean one example url bit by bit. I'm stuck now with two things which are common and always have the same structure.

1. 'By Name of correspondent, city'
2. 'Read more: link'

I'm not good at regex but I think it might help removing these two parts. Or maybe someone could suggest another way of dealing with these patterns. Thanks!

My code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import translitcodec
import codecs

def get_text(url):
    page_class = 'story-body__inner'
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")

    # remove unwanted parts by class
    try:
        soup.find('div', class_='social-embed-post social-embed-twitter').decompose()
        soup.find('div', class_='social-embed').decompose()   
        soup.find('a', class_='off-screen jump-link').decompose()
        soup.find('p', class_='off-screen').decompose()
        soup.find('a', class_='embed-report-link').decompose()
        soup.find('a', class_='story-body__link').decompose()
    except: AttributeError

    # delete unwanted tags:
    for s in soup(['figure', 'script', 'style', 'table', 'ul', 'h2', 'blockquote']):
        s.decompose()

    # use separator to separate paragraphs and subtitles!
    article_soup = [s.get_text(separator="\n", strip=True) for s in soup.find_all( 'div', {'class': page_class})]

    text = '\n'.join(article_soup)
    text = codecs.encode(text, 'translit/one').encode('ascii', 'replace') #replace traslit with ascii
    text = u"{}".format(text) #encode to unicode

    print text
    return text

url = 'http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-us-canada-41724827'
get_text(url)
```

Comment: Rather than trying to remove what you don't want, have you tried extracting only the parts you need? If you only want the main text of the news contents, you can easily extract them by filtering only the `p` tags, and then removing the two patterns you don't want (i.e., By *somebody*, Read more)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `regex` for this.

Since you only want the main content of the news article (not even headings, since you removed the `h2` tags in your code), it's much easier finding all the `p` elements first and then filtering out the items you don't need.

Three things you want to removed are:

- **Newsreader's details:** These are contained within `strong` tags inside the paragraphs. As far as I've seen, there are no other paragraphs containing `strong` elements.
- **Citations to other articles:** those beginning with "Read more: " followed by a link. Luckily, there's a fixed string before the `a` element inside paragraphs like this. So you don't need regex. You can simply find using `p.find(text='Read more: ')`.
- **Text from Twitter post:**  These don't appear on the web browser. After each twitter image embedded in the page, there's a `p` element that contains the text *"End of Twitter post  by @some_twitter_id"*. You don't want this, obviously.

**Edit:**

The main news content can be found in a single `div` with a `class` value of `story-body__inner`.

I've updated the code to fix the issue of the non-printing of paragraphs containing links. The `and` inside the second condition had to be replaced with `or`. I've added another condition `and not (p.has_attr('dir'))`, since the paragraphs containing Twitter posts have a `dir` attribute in them.

```
paragraphs = soup.find('div', {'class': 'story-body__inner'}).findAll('p')

for p in paragraphs:
    if p.find('strong') == None \
        and (p.find(text='Read more: ') == None or p.find('a') == None) \
        and not (p.has_attr('class') and 'off-screen' in p['class']) \
        and not (p.has_attr('dir')):
        print(p.text.strip())
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but if you remove all `strong` tags you also remove parts I still need to keep - like sentences with embedded links (there are three of them in this example). At the same time you still have some stuff at the start of the page and at the bottom which I need to remove - like shared options and links from the right side. And the text from tweets which duplicate the article text...

Comment: @aviss, I should've been clearer. The entire news content can be found within a single `div` with `class` value of `story-body__inner`. So, it should be `paragraphs = soup.find('div', {'class': 'story-body__inner'}).findAll('p')`. And, as far as I can tell, there are no other `strong` elements than those found in paragraphs giving you the newsreader's details. I'll confirm it once and edit my post to include those details.

Comment: There are no `strong` tags around these missing sentences indeed but somehow the code above removes them from the final text. Just to check - the first missing sentence is this: `Sgt Johnson was killed in Niger by Islamist militants this month.` Then at the top of the output I have this: `Share this with
Email
Facebook
Messenger
Messenger
Twitter
Pinterest
WhatsApp
LinkedIn
Copy this link
These are external links and will open in a new window`.

Comment: And at the bottom there are links from the right: `You know you are in too many wars in too many places when even warmonger Lindsay Graham can’t keep track anymore
Bosses are urged to help struggling staff, with mental health work plans and encouraging open discussion.` There are also bits from embedded tweets: `I had a very respectful conversation with the widow of Sgt. La David Johnson, and spoke his name from beginning, without hesitation!` which duplicate the text in the article.

Comment: @aviss, I've fixed the part where it doesn't print those linked texts. I'll update in a bit. As far as the tweets are concerned, they can be removed easily by adding (yet another) check in the `if` statement. And just for clarification, you don't want the `Share this with Email, FB, etc.`, do you? Because, right now, it doesn't get printed.

Comment: Yes, exactly! Thank you very much. Now it's CLEAN indeed. Thanks for your help. Really appreciate it!